# Why does my csharp code returns html code and not json data like Python or curl

Tags: c#, python, httpwebrequest

The problem is that when I send a POST request to an URL with python and curl, I receive JSON data: [ \"key: value\" ]

How I do it with Python:

```py
headers = { "Cookie": "xsrf_token={token}" }

url= "http://url/"

r = requests.post(check_username_url.format(self.username), headers=headers)
data = r.json()
```

How I do it with Curl:

```
curl -X POST "http://url/" -H "Cookie:xsrf_token={token}"
```

How I do it with C#

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseCookies = false; 

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://url/"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Cookie", "xsrf_token={token}"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

to summarize, my C# code returns html source code, and I want it to return JSON data like Python and Curl do. If any one can help me, thanks!

Comment: You are getting a double encoded JSON, and it could be coming as double encoded from the backend server

Comment: In C# - So far you have made a call to service . Read the response (json data) from the following statement - `var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Comment: what happens if you use PostAsync not SendAsync, as in ` var httpClient = new HttpClient(); httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "xsrf_token={token}");  response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dint mention what you want to achieve but as far as can i understand you want to retrieve JSON data from database if you are looking this kind of solution you try this code may its help you :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Yourtable", con);
            con.Close();
            SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Da.Fill(dt);
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> parentRow = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> childRow;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                childRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    childRow.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), row[col].ToString().Trim());
                }
                parentRow.Add(childRow);
            }
            string jsonString = jsSerializer1.Serialize(parentRow);
            jsonString = Regex.Replace(jsonString, @"\""\\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\\/\""", "$1");
            Response.Write("{\"data\":");
            Response.Write(jsonString);
            Response.Write("");
            Response.Write("");
            Response.Write("}");
        }
```

Comment: OP is talking to a web api - not to a database.

Comment: yeah, i am talking to a web api

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't express clearly what I want. With the python 'requests' library, I send a POST request: I receive JSON data while with csharp, I send the same request and receive html data: <!DOCTYPE html> etc...

Comment: @xxxtarnatiiion may i know your parameters ? and your output as you want?

Comment: @NitsPatel Here is what I want as an output "{'error_message': 'already taken!'}" (json string with data), here is what i receive "<!DOCTYPE html><title>"